# Is it possible to solve these simultaneous equations with integrals?

Tags: integration, integral-equations

I have the following two equations:

\begin{align}
2-3\int_{-\infty}^{y_0} f(x_0,y)\,\mathrm{d}y +\varepsilon x_0=0\\
2-3\int_{-\infty}^{x_0} f(x,y_0)\,\mathrm{d} x+\varepsilon y_0=0
\end{align}
where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are unknowns, $f$ is a pdf.

Is it possible two find $x_0$ and $y_0$ in terms of $\varepsilon$ and $f$? I know this is a very general question, but any help is greatly appreciated. If you think there is a case( for a specific pdf $f$) where it is possible to solve that would also be great.

Comment: Have you considered looking at certain derivatives?

Comment: @flawr Can you give an example?

Comment: E.g. the derivative of the first term with respect to $y_0$ or the second therm with respect to $x_0$.

Comment: @flawr The derivative of the first one wrt $y_0$ gives, by Leibniz rule, $f(x_0,y_0)-\int_{-\infty}^{y_0} \frac{\partial}{\partial y_0}f(x_0,y) dy=0$ which implies $f(x_0,y_0)=0$ but since $f$ is pdf this is something we already know. I think I don't see your point.

Comment: Are you sure your calculation is right? I get $-3f(x_0,y_0) +3\lim_{y\to -\infty} f(x_0,y) = 0$ I do not see the need for applying the Leibnitz rule.